# DropDown List on web user control is empty after postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, webusercontrol

There is a drop down list on the web user control (.ascx). 
I am binding the DropDown list control on aspx code behind page. I have tried binding it in Load , PreLoad events but its just empty after postback. I have tried the enable view state option but no luck.

I have a method in web user control for binding dropdown list and i am calling it from the main aspx code which is using this web user control .

**.ascx**

```
    public void FillDropDownList(string divisionCode, Int32 webEvevntID)
{
    DataSet dsDist = GetData(divisionCode, webEvevntID);
    ddlDist.DataSource = dsDist.Tables(0);
    ddlDist.DataTextField = "DistributorName";
    ddlDist.DataValueField = "DistNum";
    ddlDist.DataBind();
}
```

**.aspx c#**

```
private void Order_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FillDropDownList();
}
```

Comment: Do you also do in page load... if (!Page.IsPostBack) { FillDropDownList(...) } ? If not your rebind will start from the same state again.

Comment: I think you'll need to load the control on `Page_Init`.

Comment: Page_Init would only help if the control is dynamically loaded so the viewstate can be restored to it.

Answer (score 1):

As @AA said, try below

**.aspx c#**

```
private void Order_PageLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if(!IsPostBack())
    FillDropDownList();
 }
```

or you can try this:

**.ascx**

```
private void On_PageLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      if(!IsPostBack())
        FillDropDownList();
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this in pageload of user control

```
private void Order_PageLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if(!IsPostBack())
    FillDropDownList();
 }
```